# PHP mysqli new User not accepting special chars

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I wrote an loginsystem in PHP using mysqli. But it somehow don´t want into accounts with usernames that are using special chars like : '!username!' . As soon as I remove the !´s, like 'username',the login works perfect again. How can I allow special chars for the login like !,@,. etc.?

Here is my script

config.php

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

//set timezone
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

//database credentials
define('DBHOST','XXXX');
define('DBUSER','XXXX');
define('DBPASS','XXXX');
define('DBNAME','XXXX');

//application address
define('DIR','XXXX');
define('SITEEMAIL','XXXX');

try {

    //create PDO connection
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";charset=utf8mb4;dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
    //$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT);//Suggested to uncomment on production websites
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);//Suggested to comment on production websites
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    //show error
    echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
    exit;
}

//include the user class, pass in the database connection
include('classes/user.php');
include('classes/phpmailer/mail.php');
$user = new User($db);
?>
```

The actual login script:

```
    <?php
    //include config
    require_once('includes/config.php');

    //check if already logged in move to home page
    if( $user->is_logged_in() ){ header('Location: index.php'); exit(); }

    //process login form if submitted
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        if (!isset($_POST['username'])) $error[] = "Please fill out all fields";
        if (!isset($_POST['password'])) $error[] = "Please fill out all fields";

        $username = $_POST['username'];

            if (!isset($_POST['password'])){
                $error[] = 'A password must be entered';
            }
            $password = $_POST['password'];

            if($user->login($username,$password)){
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                header('Location: memberpage.php');
                exit;

            } else {
                $error[] = 'Wrong username or password or your account has not been activated.';
            }
        }



$title = 'Login';
require('layout/header.php'); 
?>
```

Comment: what is the code in the login method?

Comment: Please post your login code  ( method: login )

Comment: You mean the HTML Form?

Comment: please try with encripted username and password

Comment: No this $user->login

Comment: it should be given by the initialisation of 'PDO' in the config.php

Comment: I am not sure about that: include('classes/user.php'); < -- this is in your conig.php. In that class there is a function called login